# Unable to connect to MS SQL DB server

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, odbc

I am working on Qt-5.0.2 on Ubuntu 13.10. I have built the QODBC plugins but not able to access the db server. Here is my code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QSqlError>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setConnectOptions();

    QString dsn = QString("DRIVER={PATH};SERVER=win-l54oh3ekuur;DATABASE=LALCPlanner;UID=webdev;PWD=password;");


    db.setDatabaseName(dsn);

    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "Opened";

        QSqlQuery qry;
        if(qry.exec("select * from [TestStatus]"))
        {
            while(qry.next())
           {
                qDebug() << qry.value(0).toString();
                qDebug() << qry.value(1).toString();
           }
        }

        else
            qDebug() << "ERROR =" << db.lastError().text();

        qDebug() << "Closing!";
        db.close();
    }

    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR =" << db.lastError().text();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

here {PATH} is the path I have exported in the .bashrc file "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers"

When I run the project, the error is:

```
ERROR = "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect"
```

Btw, the code is working fine for windows.

Answer (score 1):

The code probably works for windows because you've actually got a driver named whatever you put in DRIVER={}. You can't just pass a directory in DRIVER, it needs to be the name of a driver defined in your odbcinst.ini file or the full path to the driver shared object.

You don't mention what ODBC drivers you've installed on your Ubuntu machine but I'm only aware of 2 drivers for Ubuntu that can read MS Access files and these are the Easysoft one and MDB tools (and there are loads of issues with this one). Neither of these will support magically opening a MS Access DB on a remote machine (implied by your SERVER=xxx) although the Easysoft one will read an MDB from a share (the share can be either way).

Comment: can you tell me what to fill in the DRIVER part because my odbcinst file is empty. Also its MS SQL Server not Access. And I am using unixODBC.

Comment: You've changed the question - it was "Unable to connect to MS Access DB server" when I answered it.

Comment: No one can tell you what to put in the odbcinst.ini file unless you can say what ODBC driver you are using and how/where you installed it.

Comment: ya I was mistaken about the db server earlier. I am using unixODBC and its installed in /usr/local

Comment: What you need to do it work out what ODBC driver you are going to use.